# Creating AlarmDialog in Fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So i am having an error while creating the dialog in my fragment

Here is the code:

```
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTitle(R.string.groupDetails_rename)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                ((GroupDetailsFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager())
                                        .doPositiveClick();
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
```

I am having error on `((GroupDetailsFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager())`  what should i write instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GroupDetailsFragment f = (GroupDetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");

f.doPositiveClick();
```

"tag" will be passed while you call "show()"

getSupportFragmentManager->v4
getFragmentManager->nativ

Comment: thank you. this solved my problem. here is the debugged code:

`final GroupDetailsFragment f = (GroupDetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");`

`f.doPositiveClick();`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your error has something to do with the Fragment you use. To be more specific it depends weather you use

- **android.app.Fragment** -> requires `getFragmentManager()`

or

- **android.support.v4.Fragment** -> requires `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Check your .java file of your GroupDetailsFragment and see which Fragment class you actually imported.

Furthermore your error could have something to do with your Activity not being a sub-class of FragmentActivity. Please check if your Activity **extends FragmentActivity**.

**UPDATE:**

If you are having problems getting the FragmentManager inside the Dialog, it is because "getFragmentManager()" is a method of FragmentActivity and can therefore not be used inside the Dialog. To get the Activity, simply call **getActivity()** and then get the FragmentManager:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

or to get the SupportFragmentManager()

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: here is the error: `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new 
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}`

and i am importing android.support.v4.Fragment